# Glade dialog button response ID grayed out

Tags: mingw, gtkmm, glade

I have a preferences dialog with ok and cancel in the normal action area down the bottom. I also have a browse button which I don't want to put down the bottom of the dialog.

So I have my browse button up the top but I can't set a response ID for it. The response ID field in button properties is grayed out. I tried to move all of my dialog widgets into the action area but that didn't help either.

How do I make my browse button return a response ID without moving it to the bottom of the dialog?

Edit:

From what I understand, gtk dialogs are not designed to work with buttons unless they are at the bottom. I have decided to ditch the dialog idea and go for another window instead. That way I could use the existing code to hook button events ...I hope.

Having trouble compiling the following test app though. Any ideas what the problem is?

console output:

```
g++ main.cpp examplewindow.cpp subwindow.cpp -o testsubwindow.exe -I .\ %GTKMM_INCLUDES% %GTKMM_LIBS%
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccekbJuk.o:examplewindow.cpp:(.text+0x1b0d):
undefined reference to `ExampleSubWindow::~ExampleSubWindow()'
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccekbJuk.o:examplewindow.cpp:(.text+0x1b1e):
undefined reference to `ExampleSubWindow::~ExampleSubWindow()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
\Local\Temp\ccekbJuk.o: bad reloc address 0xf in section `.text$_ZN
4sigc8internal8slot_repC2EPFPvS2_ES4_S4_[__ZN4sigc8internal8slot_repC2EPFPvS2_ES4_S4_]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,     "org.gtkmm.example");

  ExampleWindow window;

  //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
  return app->run(window);
}
```

examplewindow.h:

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
  ExampleWindow();
  virtual ~ExampleWindow();

protected:
  //Signal handlers:
  void on_button_clicked();
  void on_button2_clicked();
  void on_about_dialog_response(int response_id);

  //Child widgets:
  Gtk::Box m_VBox;
  Gtk::Label m_Label;
  Gtk::ButtonBox m_ButtonBox;
  Gtk::ButtonBox m_ButtonBox2;
  Gtk::Button m_Button;
  Gtk::Button m_Button2;
  Gtk::Window m_SubWindow;
  Gtk::AboutDialog m_Dialog;
};

class ExampleSubWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
    public:
        ExampleSubWindow();
        virtual ~ExampleSubWindow();

    protected:
        void on_button3_clicked();

        Gtk::Box s_VBox;
        Gtk::ButtonBox s_ButtonBox3;
        Gtk::Button s_Button3;
};

#endif //GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H
```

examplewindow.cpp:

```
#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <iostream>

ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()
: m_VBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
  m_Label("The AboutDialog is non-modal. "
    "You can select parts of this text while the AboutDialog is shown."),
  m_ButtonBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
  m_ButtonBox2(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
  m_Button("Show AboutDialog"),
  m_Button2("Show SubWindow")
{
  set_title("Gtk::AboutDialog example");

  add(m_VBox);

  m_VBox.pack_start(m_Label);
  m_Label.set_line_wrap(true);
  m_Label.set_selectable(true);

  m_VBox.pack_start(m_ButtonBox);
  m_ButtonBox.pack_start(m_Button);
  m_Button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleWindow::on_button_clicked) );

    m_VBox.pack_start(m_ButtonBox2);
    m_ButtonBox2.pack_start(m_Button2);
    m_Button2.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,         &ExampleWindow::on_button2_clicked));

  m_Dialog.set_transient_for(*this);

  m_Dialog.set_program_name("Example application");
  m_Dialog.set_version("1.0.0");
  m_Dialog.set_copyright("Murray Cumming");
  m_Dialog.set_comments("This is just an example application.");
  m_Dialog.set_license("LGPL");

  m_Dialog.set_website("http://www.gtkmm.org");
  m_Dialog.set_website_label("gtkmm website");

  std::vector<Glib::ustring> list_authors;
  list_authors.push_back("Murray Cumming");
  list_authors.push_back("Somebody Else");
  list_authors.push_back("AN Other");
  m_Dialog.set_authors(list_authors);

  m_Dialog.signal_response().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_about_dialog_response) );

  show_all_children();

  // The widget must be realized and mapped before grab_focus() is called.
  // That's why it's called after show_all_children().
  m_Button.grab_focus();
}

ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()
{

}

void ExampleWindow::on_about_dialog_response(int response_id)
{
  std::cout << response_id
    << ", close=" << Gtk::RESPONSE_CLOSE
    << ", cancel=" << Gtk::RESPONSE_CANCEL
    << ", delete_event=" << Gtk::RESPONSE_DELETE_EVENT
    << std::endl;

  if((response_id == Gtk::RESPONSE_CLOSE) ||
     (response_id == Gtk::RESPONSE_CANCEL) )
  {
    m_Dialog.hide();
  }
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button_clicked()
{
  m_Dialog.show();

  //Bring it to the front, in case it was already shown:
  m_Dialog.present();
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button2_clicked()
{
    ExampleSubWindow subWindow;
    subWindow.show();
}
```

subwindow.cpp

```
#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <iostream>

ExampleSubWindow::ExampleSubWindow()
: s_VBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
    s_ButtonBox3(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
    s_Button3("Test activation")
{
    add(s_VBox);

    s_VBox.pack_start(s_ButtonBox3);

    s_ButtonBox3.pack_start(s_Button3);

    s_Button3.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleSubWindow::on_button3_clicked) );
}

void ExampleSubWindow::on_button3_clicked()
{
    std::cout << "Working yet?" << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: Nevermind I figured out what was wrong with my little project. Still don't know what is wrong with the example but the main thing for me is the subwindow need to be created with "new" otherwise it will be deleted straight away.

```
ExampleSubWindow *subWindow = new ExampleSubWindow();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I figured out what was wrong with my little project. Still don't know what is wrong with the example but the main thing for me is the subwindow need to be created with "new", otherwise it will be deleted straight away.

```
ExampleSubWindow *subWindow = new ExampleSubWindow();
```

Comment: Yes. And of course you need to delete it at some point. It might be simplest to just have it as a member variable like the other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Glade. A Gtk::Dialog in Glade has a child Gtk::Box, which in turn has child Gtk::ButtonBox.  If you add Gtk::Button's to the ButtonBox, they allow Response ID to be enabled and set.  If you add a Gtk::Button to the Box in any other way (directly, or if indirectly, by, e.g., adding a Gtk::Grid to the Box and then Buttons to that Grid), Glade will not allow you to enable Response ID or set a value.

But, if you do this in the XML, it functions as expected. For example, I added a Button to the ButtonBox, and set its Response ID. I also added a Grid to Dialog's Box, and then Buttons to that grid (and as noted could not enable Response ID). I saved the .glade file, then edited it with a text editor. I went to the "action-widgets" property of the Dialog, and added "action-widget" children representing the Buttons that I'd added to the Grid.  And this Dialog worked fine: (1) clicking on the Button in the ButtonBox worked as expected, and (2) clicking on the Buttons in the Grid also worked as desired (the Dialog emitted a "response" signal, and the response ID that I manually set in the .glade file was returned from Dialog.run()).